# Spring Data MongoDB. Custom @Query with current date

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to find all documents for last 2 hours.

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends MongoRepository<Event, Long> {

    @Query("{'createdAt': {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2)}}")
    List<Event> findLive();

}
```

But there is an error:

```
09-30 14:06:33 WARN org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionController' defined in file [/Users/serge/projects/bb/bb-whlive/target/classes/bb/whlive/controller/ActionController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService' defined in file [/Users/serge/projects/bb/bb-whlive/target/classes/bb/whlive/service/EventService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'createdAt': {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2)}}
                 ^
```

I know how to do it via MongoTemplate. But is it possible to do it via MongoRepository?

P.S. In mongo shell this query works fine:

```
db.events.find({'createdAt': {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2)}}).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Query("{'createdAt': {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2)}}")
```

use following one

```
@Query("{'createdAt': { $gt: ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2 }}")
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: it does not work:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'data3Repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'createdAt': { $gt: ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5 }}
                     ^
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]